# Black-and-white camera images on GOES-S launch

Tags: imaging, ula

During todays launch of ULA's GOES-S, the public NASA TV coverage showed the rocket during its ascent, filmed from earth. Sometimes, the image changed to a more coarse grained black and white image, then changed back to a color image. The commenters never mentioned a reason. Was that an infrared or RADAR image so clouds or similar obstructions could be penetrated?

See for example [Nasa LIVE LAUNCH: GOES-S Launch Coverage - Kennedy Space Center](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K9uJ8UpSYgI) between `06:00` `and 08:00`; you can also click the screenshots below for full size.

[image: GOES-S Launch screenshot] [image: GOES-S Launch screenshot]

Comment: The cloud penetrating imaging was not very effective at 7:41 into the video :-) There is not much color to begin with, so it is difficult to know if the video at the higher magnification is color or black and white. But I believe the reason it looks black and white is because of the magnification. The sky may not be bright enough at the exposure used to show any blue, so it looks black. It is similar to photos of a total solar eclipse that show a black background.